# Created TRIGGER for two tables but getting error message

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables:

1. ORDERS - Stores all the information from my shopping cart
2. ITEMS - Stores id | scode | product | price | saleprice | inventory

I have come up with the trigger below, when an order is inserted into the database in 'orders' I want it to update the 'inventory' quantity by -1 in the 'items table'.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `order_updater` AFTER INSERT ON `orders`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE items
SET inventory = inventory - 1
WHERE id = new.id
END;
```

When I try to add it in triggers in phpMyAdmin I keep getting this message:

One or more errors have occured while processing your request:

The following query has failed: "CREATE TRIGGER `orer_update` BEFORE INSERT ON `items` FOR EACH ROW CREATE TRIGGER `order_updater` AFTER INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE items SET inventory = inventory - 1 WHERE id = new.id END;"

MySQL said: `#1303 - Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine`.

1. Can this be done with this trigger?
2. Will the trigger update a particular item or all items?
3. Can the trigger be added to the products .htm page or does it need to be in phpMyAdmin?

I'm not sure if the the code is quite right as I'm new to this, any pointers would be appreciated.

---

****UPDATE:***
phpMyAdmin : I copied this from page it says: **Version information: 4.0.8, latest stable version: 4.0.9***

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `order_updater` AFTER INSERT ON `orders`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE `items`
  SET `inventory` = `inventory` - 1
  WHERE `id` = new.`id`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**

What version of phpMyAdmin are you using? The following example, using version phpMyAdmin 4.1.0-beta2, works without problem.

[image]

Comment: Cheers still getting error message: while processing your request: The following query has failed: "CREATE TRIGGER `order_updater` BEFORE INSERT ON `items` FOR EACH ROW DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `order_updater` AFTER INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE `items` SET `inventory` = `inventory` - 1 WHERE `id` = new.`id`; END$$ DELIMITER ;" MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ CREATE TRIGGER `order_updater` AFTER INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW BEG' at line 1

Comment: Are you trying to create a trigger inside other trigger?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to this but no triggers exist at all. I'm trying to create one to do what I've outlined above. Can you not create a trigger inside another trigger?

Comment: You can not create a trigger within a trigger. Here a simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01beb) which shows how you can create a trigger.

Comment: wchiquito - cheers for that but I'm still none the wiser :-( how do you use it

Comment: I copied this from page it says: Version information: 4.0.8, latest stable version: 4.0.9

Comment: @user2940698: What was the problem?

Comment: @userwchiquito: I understand how to use sql fiddle now. However code you suggested does not do what I need it to do. I have been given this bit of code but I really do not know what to do with it, it is supposed to extract order details from the cart and update a stock table. Here is the code: $cartitems = explode("~",$cart);
foreach($cartitems as $item) {
$itemvars = explode(" : ",$item);
$description = trim($itemvars[0]);
$quantity = $itemvars[1];
$price = $itemvars[2];
$units = $itemvars[3];
$code = trim($itemvars[4]);

...update stock table logic here...
}